# Need some help porting Java code Android Studio to C# Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, porting

I need some help porting a piece of Java code to C#. The code is about a post request to a web api, to make the connection I used Volley in Java and I've already installed the NuGet in Visual Studio. I have trouble converting a StringRequest function to C#.

This is the piece of code that I'm currently trying to port in C# but I get errors when declaring the params in C#. For example it doesn't recognize the Request.Method and the new Response.Listener.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                Log.i("Volley Response", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType()
            {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody()
            {
                try
                {
                    return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        return stringRequest;
```

If someone could be so nice to help me porting it to C# I would be very happy.

Comment: SO is not a code-porting service

Comment: Ok, sorry for the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself without using Volley and without porting the java code.

Sorry again for asking for porting, I didn't know that it's not something i should ask here. Thanks to jrswgtr for letting me know.

This is the code for making a simple POST request to a web api, getting the values from two editbox and sending them after clicking a button.

```cs
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Button invia = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.submit);
            EditText utenteInserito = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.utente);
            EditText passwordInserito = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.password);

            invia.Click += async delegate
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string utente = utenteInserito.Text;
                string password = passwordInserito.Text;
                string json = "{'user': '"+utente+"','password': '"+password+"'}";
                string URL = "http://192.168.1.11:57279/api/utente";
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            };
        }
    }
```

**Updated code using a defined Model**

```
invia.Click += delegate
            {
                string user = utenteInserito.Text;
                string password = passwordInserito.Text;
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.11:57279/api/");
                var utente = new Utente
                {
                    user = user,
                    password = password
                };
                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Utente>("utente", utente);
                postTask.Wait();
            };
```